# Only importing one function from a module can also import all sub-functions?

Tags: python

I have two python files:

AAA.py

```
def func1():
    print('func1')

def func2():
    eval('func1')()
    print('func2')
```

BBB.py

```
from AAA import func2

func2()
```

In BBB.py, I am not doing "from AAA import *", only func2 got imported, how could python load func1, what's happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from AAA import func2
```

is essentially the same as

```
import AAA
func2 = AAA.func2
```

Python has to interpret the entire file in order to find the functions you want.